# How to properly declare functions in C++?

Tags: c++, function, header, declaration

I found a couple of examples onlines but I can't figure out how to properly declare functions in my .cpp vs my header file. Can you help me figure out where I'm going wrong? Here is my code:

Translator.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Translator.h"
#include "Model.h" 

using namespace std;

  // Translate English word method
    translateEnglishWord(std::string word) {
    Model model;
    std::string result = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < word.size(); ++i) {
        char c = word[i];
      if (c == 'A' || c == 'E' || c == 'I' || c == 'O' || c == 'U' ||
          c == 'a' || c == 'e' || c == 'i' || c == 'o' || c == 'u') {
        result += model.translateSingleVowel(c);
      } else if ((c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') || (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')) {
        result += model.translateSingleConsonant(c);
      } else {
        result += c;
      }
    }
    return result;
  }

int main() {
    Translator translator;
    std::cout << translator.translateEnglishWord("Hello") << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Translator.h:

```
#ifndef TRANSLATOR_H //header guard: prevents C++ from including the same header file multiple times
#define TRANSLATOR_H 
#include <string>

class Translator {
 public:
  // Default constructor
  Translator() {}
    // Default deconstructor
  ~Translator() {}


    // Translate English word method
  std::string translateEnglishWord(std::string word) {
      std::string result = "";
      return result;
  }
};
#endif
```

model.h:

```
#ifndef MODEL_H
#define MODEL_H 
#include <string>

class Model {
 public:
  // Default constructor
  Model() {}
  // Default destructor
  ~Model() {}


  // Translate single consonant method
  std::string translateSingleConsonant(char c) {
      std::string result = "";
      return result;
  }

  // Translate single vowel method
  std::string translateSingleVowel(char c) {
      std::string result = "";
      return result;
  }

  
  
};

#endif
```

Model.cpp:

```
#include "Model.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


  // Translate single consonant method
  std::string translateSingleConsonant(char c) {
    std::string result = "";
    if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') {
      result += c;
      result += 'o';
      result += c;
    } else if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') {
      result += c;
      result += 'o';
      result += c;
    }
    return result;
  }

  // Translate single vowel method
  std::string translateSingleVowel(char c) {
    std::string result = "";
    if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') {
      result += c;
    } else if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') {
      result += c;
    }
    return result;
  }
```

I am not sure where to properly declare my functions. I also don't know where to put the default constructor and destructor.

Comment: This endless chain of `||` operators is a sign you really need to learn about data structures. Consider [`std::set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) for example. For characters you can even use a simple `std::string` that defines all possible letters, and just check that the letter is in the string. Slower, but still fine in most cases.

Comment: Regarding constructor and destructor - if they do nothing, just remove them. Compiler will generate them for you.